# Работа с двумя listbox объектами в модуле Tkinter

Tags: python, gui, tkinter

Создал простую программу с двумя списками, и выделяю в них элементы.
Хочу добиться того, чтобы в обеих списках было выделено по одному элементу.

Но если я выбрал в одним списке элемент, то при переходе в другой список, фокус с выделенного элемента снимается.

Пример:

```
def Get(event):    
     print event.widget.curselection()


from Tkinter import *    

r = Tk()    
l = Listbox(r)    
l1 = Listbox(r)
l.insert(END, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
l1.insert(END, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')    
l.pack()    
l1.pack()    
l1.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", Get)
l.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", Get)

r.mainloop()
```

Comment: Решил заменить Listbox  на Combobox, т.к. мне по сути нужно было три списка на форме. В итоге получилось два выпадающих списка и листбокс :)

Answer (score 1):

По умолчанию при переходе к другому списку подсветка строки текущего списка снимается. Чтобы избежать такого поведения и добиться сохранения подсветки, нужно у элемента типа `ListBox` установить параметр `exportselection` в нулевое значение:

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()

leftListBox = tkinter.Listbox(exportselection=0)
leftListBox.insert(tkinter.END, "left 1", "left 2", "left 3")
leftListBox.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)

middleListBox = tkinter.Listbox()
middleListBox.insert(tkinter.END, "middle 1", "middle 2", "middle 3")
middleListBox.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)

rightListBox = tkinter.Listbox()
rightListBox.insert(tkinter.END, "right 1", "right 2", "right 3")
rightListBox.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

При этом есть одна интересная тонкость. Этот параметр не только заставляет список сохранять подсветку при переходе к другому списку, но также и сохраняет подсветку другого списка, из которого к нему совершён переход. В примере выше будет следующее поведение:

- У `leftListBox` выделенная строка будет подсвечиваться всегда.
- После выделения строки в `middleListBox` (`rightListBox`) и переходу к `leftListBox` строка в `middleListBox` (`rightListBox`) останется подсвеченной.
- После выделения строки в `middleListBox` и переходу к `rightListBox` подсветка строки в `middleListBox` будет снята.